# JavaScript copy a class atributes and create a new identical object

Tags: javascript, class, object, this

**I have a class that copy objects and it looks like this:**

```
Class CoppyComponent {
    constructor(element) {
        return Object.assgin(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(element)), element);
     }
}
```

**I have another class to create HTML elements that use an array to keep track of the HTML elements created**

```
Class Component {
    constructor(){
        this.arr = [];
    }
}
```

**I use the classes this way:**

```
const hi = new Component();
hi.CreateEl({ type: "h1", text: "Hello", parrent: ".a" });
hi.CreateEl({ type: "h2", text: "Hello", parrent: ".a" });
hi.CreateEl({ type: "h3", text: "Hello", parrent: ".a" });
hi.CreateEl({ type: "h4", text: "Hello", parrent: ".a" });
hi.CreateEl({ type: "h6", text: "Hello", parrent: ".a" });
const h1Copy = new CoppyComponent(hi);
`h1Copy.load(".b");`
```

**createEl methid just create a new HTML element**

**load method just modify the parent element**
HTML elements go into div with class b only instead of both divs (a, b)

I console.log both objects (hi, h1Copy) and are identical
What I think the problem is but I am not sure is that both objects share the same array.

Comment: They aren't in the same array.  `this.arr` is a member of the instance, not the Class.

Comment: If i modify the parent of html of hi -> hi.load(".a") all the h elements move into a div and b div remain empty

Comment: There's too much missing from your question.  What is `Component.CreateEl`?  What is `Component.load`?